# Pandas RegEx extract first match on substring, wrong number of items passed

Tags: python, regex, string, pandas

I am trying to pull out specific characters from a substring in Pandas to populate a new column. Each row has a similar format, but not similar enough to just slice it. Each row below is a string in a single column:

```
   frog (1 column-string)
   _______________________________________________
1  OU812   2687BA   LM356   6342HK   BLAD   HA43S
2  OU635   GH3S5  3211CF SHN1   5875HK   BOOD   FR53G
3  OU525   3414MF   5385HK   ASD28   6338HK   OR53J
```

Ultimately I'm looking to isolate the three digits preceding the first substring (ignoring the first one) ending with HK, so row 1 would be 342, 2 would be 875, and 3 would be 385.

My assumption has been that I would need to extract the 6 characters that end with HK and then slice out the three characters I need (if anyone has ideas on how to skip that step it would be great, too).

My main problem is that the code I'm using returns a "wrong number of items passed" error.

```
df['crunch'] = df['frog'].str.extract("(\d{4})(HK)?", expand=True)
```

I had thought that the ? would stop the code from getting more than the one instance but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: Can you add `df['crunch'].head(5)`?

Comment: @Bharathshetty I don't understand what you're asking me to do? df['crunch'] is a column. Also, this is hypothetical data / code so I can't really show any actual output.

Comment: Im asking it because you are trying to extract from that specific column. So

Comment: Each row is a single string (1 column named frog)

Comment: @MaxU no, I'm extracting the substring from frog to create column crunch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC and you have a single column - `frog`:

```
In [217]: df
Out[217]:
                                                frog
1     OU812   2687BA   LM356   6342HK   BLAD   HA43S
2  OU635   GH3S5  3211CF SHN1   5875HK   BOOD   F...
3   OU525   3414MF   5385HK   ASD28   6338HK   OR53J

In [218]: df['crunch'] = df['frog'].str.extract(r'\s+\d(\d+)HK\s+', expand=True)

In [219]: df
Out[219]:
                                                frog crunch
1     OU812   2687BA   LM356   6342HK   BLAD   HA43S    342
2  OU635   GH3S5  3211CF SHN1   5875HK   BOOD   F...    875
3   OU525   3414MF   5385HK   ASD28   6338HK   OR53J    385
```

> Why your code didn't work?

you have specified two capturing groups (in parentheses) in RegEx:

```
In [202]: df['frog'].str.extract("(\d{4})(HK)?", expand=True)
Out[202]:
      0   1
1  6342  HK
2  5875  HK
3  5385  HK
```

and you tried to assign those two columns into a single column `frog`

Comment: This might be what he wanted. I thought he had 6 columns

Comment: @Bharathshetty, same here, that's why i asked OP for a clarification...

Comment: Not getting that.

With 
    ("(\d{5})(KT)?", expand=True)

With ("(\d{5})(KT)?", expand=False)

Comment: Using the new sample, I'm getting a new row, crunch with:

       crunch
    1 2687
    2 3211
    3 3414

Comment: Added [^\d{4}] to the head of it and that got me what I needed. 

Many thanks!